# SliceMap when using PageSize

Tags: go, cassandra, pagination, gocql

I am trying to implement paging but when I use SliceMap with PageSize I get all the rows - do you know why and what to do? 
Note: I need the row maps keyed by CQL column mames.

```
iter := session.Query("SELECT * FROM paging").PageSize(10).Iter()
slicemap, err := iter.SliceMap()
saveState := iter.PageState()
fmt.Println(slicemap)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
iter := session.Query("SELECT * FROM paging").PageState(nil).PageSize(10).Iter()
```

please use like this